# How to use lists to remove a "grab item" option?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner in coding and I'm currently working on an rpg. I am trying to implement a "grab item" option with lists when there is a grabbable item in the room. But after I grab the item, the item is still grabbable. Can someone give me a simple solution a beginner can understand? (I need to turn this in tomorrow.) The rooms with the grabbable items are:

- 'stairs 
  going up and a pokeball.' floor 2 room 1 (currentFloor == 1 and currentRoom == 0)
- 'a pokeball!' floor 3 room 2 (currentFloor == 2 and currentRoom == 1)
- 'stairs going up and 2 pokeballs!' floor 3 room 4 (currentFloor == 2 and currentRoom == 3)
- 'a potion!' floor 4 room 3 (currentFloor == 3 and currentRoom == 2)

---

```
def foo(m):
"""
Valid commands the player can input.
"""
if m.lower() == 'left' or m.lower() == 'right' or m.lower() == 'help' or m.lower() == 'pokemon' or m.lower() == 'bag' or m.lower() == 'up' or m.lower() == 'down' or m.lower() == 'grab':
    return True
else:
    return False

print("You are finally a Pokemon trainer! Today, you have gotten your very 
first Pokemon, a Bulbasaur!")
name = input("What will you name your Bulbasaur? ")
print("Unfortunately, " + name + " doesn't seem to obey or like you...")
print("You try to be friendly to " + name + ", but it just won't listen...")
print("As " + name + " was busy ignoring you, something seems to catch its 
attention and it runs off!")
print("You chase after " + name + ", but it's too fast! You see it running 
into an abandoned Pokeball Factory.")
print("You must explore the abandoned Pokeball Factory and find " + name + " 
before something happens to it!")
print()
print("You may input 'help' to display the commands.")
print()

gamePlay = True
floors = [['floor 1 room 1', 'floor 1 room 2', 'floor 1 room 3', 'floor 1 
room 4'],['floor 2 room 1', 'floor 2 room 2', 'floor 2 room 3', 'floor 2 
room 4', 'floor 2 room 5'],['floor 3 room 1', 'floor 3 room 2', 'floor 3 
room 3', 'floor 3 room 4'],['floor 4 room 1', 'floor 4 room 2', 'floor 4 
room 3', 'floor 4 room 4']]
floorsFeature = [['a potion! But upon closer inspection you find that is it 
used up...', 'nothing here.', 'stairs going up.', 'a Squirtle.'],['stairs 
going up and a pokeball.', 'a FIRE!!!', 'stairs going down.', 'a 
Charmander.'],['stairs going down.', 'a pokeball!', 'a door covered in 
vines.', 'stairs going up and 2 pokeballs!'],['your Bulbasaur!!!', 'a 
pokeball! But it is broken...', 'a potion!', 'an Eevee with a key tied 
around its neck and stairs going down.']]
currentFloor = 0
currentRoom = 1
pokemonGot = []
count = 0
bagItems = ['pokeball']
countItems = 1

while gamePlay == True:
    print("You are on " + floors[currentFloor][currentRoom] + ". You find " 
+ floorsFeature[currentFloor][currentRoom])
    move = input("What would you like to do? ")
    while foo(move) == False:
        move = input("There's a time and place for everything, but not now! 
What would you like to do? ")
    if move.lower() == 'grab':
        if currentFloor == 1 and currentRoom == 0 or currentFloor == 2 and 
currentRoom == 1 or currentFloor == 2 and currentRoom == 3 or currentFloor 
== 3 and currentRoom == 2:
            print("Grabbed it!")
        if currentFloor == 1 and currentRoom == 0:
            floorsFeature[1].pop(0)
            floorsFeature[1].insert(0,'stairs going up.')
            bagItems.append('pokeball')
            countItems + 1
        if currentFloor == 2 and currentRoom == 1:
            floorsFeature[2].pop(1)
            floorsFeature[2].insert(1,'nothing here.')
            bagItems.append('pokeball')
            countItems + 1
        if currentFloor == 2 and currentRoom == 3:
            floorsFeature[2].pop(3)
            floorsFeature[2].insert(3,'stairs going up.')
            bagItems.append('pokeball')
            bagItems.append('pokeball')
            countItems + 1
        if currentFloor == 3 and currentRoom == 2:
            floorsFeature[3].pop(2)
            floorsFeature[3].insert(2,'nothing here.')
            bagItems.append('potion')
            countItems + 1
        else:
            print("There is nothing to grab!")
     if move.lower() == 'left':
        if currentRoom > 0:
            currentRoom = currentRoom - 1
            print("Moved to " + floors[currentFloor][currentRoom] + ".")
        else:
            print("*Bumping noise* Looks like you can't go that way...")
    elif move.lower() == 'right':
        if currentRoom < len(floors) - 1:
            currentRoom = currentRoom + 1
            print("Moved to " + floors[currentFloor][currentRoom] + ".")
        else:
            print("*Bumping noise* Looks like you can't go that way...")
    elif move.lower() == 'up':
        if currentFloor == 0 and currentRoom == 2 or currentFloor == 1 and 
 currentRoom == 0 or currentFloor == 2 and currentRoom == 2:
            currentFloor += 1
            print("Moved to " + floors[currentFloor][currentRoom] + ".")
        else: 
            print("*Bumping noise* Looks like you can't go that way...")
    elif move.lower() == 'down':
        if currentFloor == 1 and currentRoom == 2 or currentFloor == 2 and 
currentRoom == 0 or currentFloor == 3 and currentRoom == 2:
            currentFloor -= 1
            print("Moved to " + floors[currentFloor][currentRoom] + ".")
    elif move.lower() == 'help':
        print("Input 'right' to move right. Input 'left' to move left. Input 
'pokemon' to see what Pokemon are on your team. Input 'bag' to see the items 
you are carrying. Input 'up' or 'down' when there are stairs. Input 'grab' 
to grab a grabbable item. Input 'help' to see the commands again.")
    elif move.lower() == 'pokemon':
        if count == 0:
            print("There are no Pokemon on your team.")
        else:
            print("The Pokemon on your team are: " + ", ".join(pokemonGot) + 
".")
    elif move.lower() == 'bag':
        if countItems <= 0:
            print("There are no items in your bag.")
        else:
            print("The items in your bag are: " + ", ".join(bagItems) + ".")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you avoid hard-coding the locations of the grabbable items. Instead, put the grabbable items for each room in a separate data structure from the other "features" of the room. When enter a room, check both the features data structure, and the grabbalbes data structure. If the latter is empty, you don't mention any items.

This makes things easier because after an item has been grabbed, you can just remove it from the grabbables data structure. Once it's gone, the room will behave just like there was never any item there in the first place.

Comment: Can you please give me an example for a grabbable data structure? I am unsure how to do it.

Comment: There are many ways you could implement it, but the simplest might be to make it look exactly like your `floorsFeature` list. Just put `None` in the grabbables structure for each room there's nothing to grab.